# From parametric to symmetric form

Tags: parametric, parametrization

I'm studying parametric equations and the manual I'm following does not explain how it goes from parametric to symmetric form. 
The problem is:

$$
x(t)=3\cos^2 t\\
y(t)=3\sin^2 t
$$

I only know that the solution is $x+y=3$. Until now, to deal with this kind of problem, I just replace the dummy variable on the other equation and I got the symmetric equation. But now, I have no idea how to deal with the cos and sin squares. So, how I go from parametric to symmetric equations in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
x(t) + y(t) = 3 \cos^2 t + 3 \sin^2 t
 = 3 \left(\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t\right)
 = 3 \cdot 1
 = 3,
$$
so the resulting curve is $x+y=3$.

Note that as $t$ travels from $0$ to $2\pi$, you have $0 \le x,y \le 3$, so the resulting curve is a line segment, even if you consider larger ranges of $t$.

Comment: Whoa! That was easy, thanks you very much! Just a side question, it's always possible add the parametric equations to get the symmetric form?

Comment: There's a typo in the answer. It should be 3*cos ^2 not 2.

Comment: @WnGatRC456 thanks, please feel free to change yourself next time :)

Comment: @emek it's an often used trick but not always helpful. For example, if $x = \cos t$ and $y = \sin^2 t$, you would want to add $x^2+y$ instead. The idea is to fit the commonly used trig identities, like the one in this answer.

Comment: I understand. Thanks again :)

Comment: @gt6989b you can't make edits less than 6 characters unless you're the author of the question.

Comment: @WnGatRC456 thank you, i did not know :)